# Whats wrong with this that causes my integration tests to be marked as source rather than test source?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, source-sets

This works fine from the command line but IntelliJ displays the integrationTest sources as if they were source and not test source.

Gradle code:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/it/java')
            output.classesDir   = "$buildDir/classes/it"
        }

        def resourceDir = file('src/it/resources')
        if (resourceDir.exists()) {
            resources.srcDir resourceDir
            output.resourcesDir = "$buildDir/resources/it"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an IntelliJ bug. Please vote for it.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151925